# How calculate fiber length

Tags: computer-vision

I need help calculating fiber length. I found all the coordinate values of center line of fiber by using regional maximal of euclidean distance. Here is the image that I got after applying regional maximal of euclidean distance. Now I want to draw a line on each fiber by using these points how can I do that so that I can extract each fiber length automatically. I tried to do it by using spline curve fitting. But the problem is I was not able to initiate the starting and ending point of fiber. How can I calculate each fiber length?

[image: fiber image after applying regional maximal]

---

```
   close all;
clear all;
clc
ima=imread('ecm61.png');
ima=bwareaopen(ima,50);
[rowsInImage,columnImage]=size(ima);
skel= bwmorph(ima,'skel',Inf);
figure 
imshow(skel)
B = bwmorph(skel, 'branchpoints');
E = bwmorph(skel, 'endpoints');
[x,y] = find(E);
%plot(x,y,'+')
B_loc = find(B);
Dmask = false(size(skel));
for k = 1:numel(y)
    D = bwdistgeodesic(skel,y(k),x(k));
    distanceToBranchPt = min(D(B_loc));
    Dmask(D < distanceToBranchPt) =true;
end
skelD = skel - Dmask;

figure
imshow(skelD);
hold all;
[x,y] = find(B); plot(y,x,'ro')
numberOfEndpoints=length(y);
% Label the image.  Gives each separate segment a unique ID label number.
[labeledImage, numberOfSegments] = bwlabel(skelD);
fprintf('There are %d endpoints on %d segments.\n', numberOfEndpoints, numberOfSegments);
% Get the label numbers (segment numbers) of every endpoint.
for k = 1 : numberOfEndpoints
    thisRow = x(k);
    thisColumn = y(k);
    %line([endPointRows(k),endPointColumns(k)],[endPointRows(k+1),endPointColumns(k+1)])
    % Get the label number of this segment
    theLabels(k) = labeledImage(thisRow, thisColumn);
    fprintf('Endpoint #%d at (%d, %d) is in segment #%d.\n', k, thisRow, thisColumn, theLabels(k));
end

% For each endpoint, find the closest other endpoint
% that is not in the same segment
for k = 1 : numberOfEndpoints
    thisRow = x(k);
    thisColumn =y(k);
    % Get the label number of this segment
    thisLabel = theLabels(k);

    otherEndpointIndexes = setdiff(1:numberOfEndpoints, k);
    %if mustBeDifferent
        % If they want to consider joining only end points that reside on different segments
        % then we need to remove the end points on the same segment from the "other" list.
        % Get the label numbers of the other end points.
        %otherLabels = theLabels(otherEndpointIndexes);
        %onSameSegment = (otherLabels == thisLabel); % List of what segments are the same as this segment
        %otherEndpointIndexes(onSameSegment) = []; % Remove if on the same segment
    %end

    % Now get a list of only those end points that are on a different segment.
    otherCols = y(otherEndpointIndexes);
    otherRows = x(otherEndpointIndexes);

    % Compute distances
    distances = sqrt((thisColumn - otherCols).^2 + (thisRow - otherRows).^2);
    % Find the min
    [minDistance, indexOfMin] = min(distances);
    nearestX = otherCols(indexOfMin);
    nearestY = otherRows(indexOfMin);

    %if minDistance < longestGapToClose;
    if minDistance < rowsInImage
        % Draw line from this endpoint to the other endpoint.
        line([thisColumn, nearestX], [thisRow, nearestY], 'Color', 'g', 'LineWidth', 2);
        fprintf('Drawing line #%d, %.1f pixels long, from (%d, %d) on segment #%d to (%d, %d) on segment #%d.\n', ...
            k, minDistance, thisColumn, thisRow, theLabels(k), nearestX, nearestY, theLabels(indexOfMin));
    end
end
title('Endpoints Linked by Green Lines', 'FontSize', 12, 'Interpreter', 'None');
```

[after using edge linking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYVJl.jpg)

Comment: In future, please edit your code into your question, rather than posting it as an answer. Also, I'd recommend you edit your question to be more precise about what isn't working; it's not entirely clear at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

1. Skeletonize
2. [Pruning](http://www.dabi.temple.edu/~shape/partshape/structure/3.php)
3. Find the different path at each intersection. It will give you the different segments, and you can reconnect them using the orientation.

Comment: Thank you.But I have few questions.what is pruning?how can i find different path at each intersection?

Comment: I've had a link for the pruning, but you have plenty others on Google. It's the operation of removing small branches. A pixel with more than two neighbors is an intersection, and the intersection are the extremities of the path.

Comment: Thankyou.I will follow that idea.

Comment: I did first 2 .How can i find the orientation?

Comment: A pixel with more than 2 neighbors is at an intersection!

Comment: Thank you.Trying to implement your idea.

Comment: I use the following algorithm find the brunch point.TRY TO CONNECT those points.But problem is could not able to connect all the points .According to your suggestion i need to find the intersection and then joint points by using orientation.

Comment: By using the branch point i got the intersection point also some other points.How can i only keep the intersect point and remove other point?I would like to post my code here ,but could not able to post it.